# UITextfield with tag in UITableViewCell returning null if more than one section of table is visible

Tags: uitableview, uitextfield

I have a static UITableView with 4 different prototype cells. Instead of working with 1 reusable cell including a switch, I used 3 different "switchcell-prototypes", switchCell1 - to switchCell3 (I was lazy). The first switchCell is in section 1 of the table, along with a textBoxCell I made. The other 2 switchCells are in section 2.
I am accessing the switches and the textbox within the cells with tags.

Just to give it a try I changed my code so that the tableview now only has one section. Everything is now shown, with no switching to hide certain cells. Seems that it's not the issue of 2 sections, but that there are cells coming after the one having the textfield in it. Weird.

The properties of the switches and the textbox are strong.

This is how I access my switches and the textbox:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

switchCellLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:10];
dailyLimitSwitch = (UISwitch *)[cell viewWithTag:20];

[dailyLimitSwitch setOn:[settings boolForKey:@"limitBool"]];

textBoxCellLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:30];
dailyLimitEntry = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:40];
```

This is the action for one of the switches:

```
- (IBAction)dailyLimitSwitch:(id)sender {


if ([settings boolForKey:@"limitBool"]==NO) {
    [settings setBool:YES forKey:@"limitBool"];
}else if ([settings boolForKey:@"limitBool"]==YES){
    [settings setBool:NO forKey:@"limitBool"];
    [settings setDouble:(0) forKey:@"limitDouble"];
```

I am using the same kind of action for the textbox, too. `- (IBAction)dailyLimitEntry:(id)sender`

So, here is the complete IBAction for my UITextField
I basically get the string from the UITextField, make it into a number to check that the user entered a real number, then I create an integer to see if it's a decimal number as I only want integers and then I "save" the entry in some NSUserDefaults. Like posted initially, this works as long as only one section of the table is visible. As soon as I show the switches in the second section, the textfield returns null.

```
- (IBAction)dailyLimitEntry:(id)sender {

NSNumberFormatter *newLimitFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];

[newLimitFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[newLimitFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:3];

NSNumber *newLimitNr = [[NSNumber alloc]init];
newLimitNr = [newLimitFormatter numberFromString:dailyLimitEntry.text];

double newLimitDouble = [[newLimitFormatter numberFromString:dailyLimitEntry.text]doubleValue];

int newLimitInt = [newLimitNr intValue];


if (newLimitNr == nil || (newLimitDouble - newLimitInt)>0) {

    UIAlertView *invalidLimitAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Limit" message:@"Invalid limit" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [invalidLimitAlert show];

}else{

    [settings setDouble:newLimitDouble forKey:@"limitDouble"];

    if (![settings doubleForKey:@"countDouble"]==0) {
        double newRemainingDouble = [settings doubleForKey:@"limitDouble"]-[settings doubleForKey:@"countDouble"];

        [settings setDouble:newRemainingDouble forKey:@"remainingDouble"];

    }else if ([settings doubleForKey:@"countDouble"]==0){
        double newRemainingDouble = [settings doubleForKey:@"limitDouble"];

        [settings setDouble:newRemainingDouble forKey:@"remainingDouble"];
    }
}

[dailyLimitEntry resignFirstResponder];
```

}

And finally my cellForRowAtIndexPath:
(This is from where everything still worked. I've added my new "switchcells" from IB by referencing them like the switchcell here and added the numbers 1 and 2 to the identifier (switchcell1 and switchcell2) so that they are different.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];


if (section == 0 && row == 0) {
    cellIdentifier = @"switchCell";
}
if (section == 0 && row == 1) {
    cellIdentifier = @"textBoxCell";
}

NSArray *labelsForCurrentSection = [sectionLabels objectAtIndex:section];

NSString *labelForCurrentCell = [[NSString alloc]init];

labelForCurrentCell = [labelsForCurrentSection objectAtIndex:row];


cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


switchCellLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:10];
dailyLimitSwitch = (UISwitch *)[cell viewWithTag:20];

[dailyLimitSwitch setOn:[settings boolForKey:@"limitBool"]];


textBoxCellLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:30];
dailyLimitEntry = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:40];

switchCellLabel.text = labelForCurrentCell;
textBoxCellLabel.text = labelForCurrentCell;


if ([settings doubleForKey:@"limitDouble"]==0) {
    dailyLimitEntry.text = @"";
}else{

NSString *dailyLimitStr = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%0.f",[settings doubleForKey:@"limitDouble"]];
dailyLimitEntry.text = dailyLimitStr;

}

return cell;
```

}

Here is the problem:
All switches and the textbox are linked to the interface via IBAction.
I can set my userdefaults with all 3 switches, no matter if the 2nd section is visible or not. But the textfield returns it's value if my 2nd section isn't visible and returns null if it's visible.

Any ideas? It's really driving me crazy.

Comment: Post the code that is in your `- (IBAction)dailyLimitEntry:(id)sender` since that is what you are having a problem with.  Also, your *entire*  `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath` would probably be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue and it's now working with multiple sections and cells following my UITextField-cell.

Here's what I did:

- Create a prototype cell holding a UITextField
- Connect the UITextField via an IBAction "didEndOnExit" to .h
- When setting up the UITextField-Cell in cellForRowForIndexPath, reference the UITextField like this `dailyLimitEntry = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:35];` (this way, the content can be set from the userdefaults via dailyLimitEntry.text
- In the IBAction of the didEndEditing of the UITextField `- (IBAction)dailyLimitEntry:(id)sender` I access the contents of the UITextField from whatever the sender gives me back. To do so, I've set up a temporary variable like this `UITextField *cellDailyLimitEntryTextField= (UITextField*)sender;` (the long variable name is only so I can remember what I did when I come back later.
- Now I can retrieve the value of the textfield via `cellDailyLimitEntryTextField.text` and proceed with the rest of my code.

The UITextField now behaves like it wasn't even located within a cell of a tableview and getting and setting the content is straight forward.

Whether this is ok for Apple, I'll know as soon as I submit my app. But I basically make apps I want for myself ;-)

By the way, no UITextFieldDelegate and its methods were needed. I think that setting up my cell creates an instance of a UITextField which I didn't access properly to receive the content. Like stated in my question, everything worked fine as long as no more cells followed the UITextFieldCell. Now I've opened up my UITableView to its initial state with 2 sections, and it works.

If you like my answer to my question, please vote for it.